# Regex for credit card numbers and details

Tags: regex

I have got the Regex for just the credit card number but i want the numbers after that.
Let's say i have a string - "`5189410208765027|08|2024|846`".

I want this to be matched via regex. The regex i got for just "`5189410208765027`" id - "`^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|[25][1-7][0-9]{14}|6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})$`"

Can anyone just tell the regex to match the whole string?

Comment: Please refer [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html) to get the basic regex patterns for the various types of CC providers.

Comment: the one i mentioned in the question is for all kinds of CC providers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
^((?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|[25][1-7][0-9]{14}|6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11}))\|([0-9]+)\|([0-9]+)\|([0-9]+)$
```

[See RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zd0PKW/1/)

The credit card number will be in capture group 1. Capture groups 2, 3 and 4 will have the next 3 numbers.